# How can I show a count value in SQL instead of listing out many rows in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I show a count value in SQL dependent on the value of a field. If I have a table called Orders that has a CustomerID:

```
CustID
Cust1
Cust2
Cust3
Cust1
```

How can I have it display repetition count:

```
CustID  RepCount
Cust1     2
Cust2     1
Cust3     1
Cust1     2
```

Comment: If you add some sample data and wanted result, and it will be easier to understand what you mean. Also, have you tried any select at all, how does it look?

Comment: Did you really want Cust1 displayed twice?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CustID, COUNT(CustID) as 'RepCount'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CustID
```

You can also have result by this small query

Answer (score 1):

First get a count grouped by custID in a sub query then join back..  If window sets worked in mysql, over partition by custID would be a better approach avoiding a subquery, as it doesn't... a subquery is needed.

```
SELECT O.custID, B.RepCount 
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) RepCount, CustID 
            FROM Orders 
            GROUP BY CustID) B
  ON B.CustId = O.custID
```

This approach is needed if you really want to see the same cust# listed multiple times.  If not then a simple select count and group by would work. (as others have illustrated)